# Prusa Mk3 printing rough surfaces

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3, troubleshooting

My Prusa Mk3 has been making this sort of rough surface on prints, and I'm not sure what caused this. I am printing with PLA Prusament with 0.2 mm layer height at the preset for PLA. What is this, and how can I fix it?

[image: Print with rough surface finish]

<strike>Edit: Changed absolutely nothing, tried again and problem solved!</strike>

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! Your picture is really hard to see ... is there any way to get a better quality image posted? Also, you might want to post what type of filament you are using and the settings used to print it. If this is a regular pattern found on Thingiverse (or some other accessible library), please post a link to it so we can understand what exactly you are trying to print.

Comment: Added better picture and more info

Comment: I'm no expert (by far) but it looks to me like you've got a warped bed. The rough texture would be areas which pull away from the print head, while the smooth part is right in the ball park. Just my gut check here as like I said, I'm no expert.

Comment: @Geekdude3 is this the top or bottom of your print?

Comment: @PerplexedDipole from the exposed infill on the left I guess top

Answer (score 1):

The OP was not able to reproduce the problem as can be taken from an edit to his question:

> Changed absolutely nothing, tried again and problem solved!

*To honor the Q/A approach used on SE sites, this comment has been converted to a community answer, that once voted for will not make this question pop up once in a while.*

Comment: This is an stability temperature issue. thats way some times can't be reproduce until the user have the same ambient and the time of stabilization temperature. But this have solution mechanically, by parameters, by time.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like your nozzle is too hot. Try turning the temp down by 5 degrees at a time and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot and see if that's the issue